# Do U.S. Wilderness areas allow bridges?

Tags: united-states, wilderness

A U.S. [wilderness area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Wilderness_Preservation_System) prohibits *road-building and other forms of development*.  Are bridges on hiking trail permitted, or are all river crossings in wilderness areas necessarily unbridged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are bridges in wilderness areas, this one was in the Wind River Range for example.

[image]

On there other hand, there are restrictions on the tools used in a wilderness area such as not allowing power tools such as chainsaws.

Comment: Impressed by trail crews for maintaining bridges and trails without power tools!